# How to ignore a line in ifstream in C++?

Tags: c++, file, file-io, io, ifstream

I want to read a text file in C++ and I have done it using ifstream.
The file:

```
// The range of 'horizontal' indices, inclusive
// E.g. if the range is 0-4, then the indices are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
GridX_IdxRange=0-8

// The range of 'vertical' indices, inclusive
// E.g. if the range is 0-3, then the indices are 0, 1, 2, 3
GridY_IdxRange=0-8

// [x,y] grid-areas which are occupied by cities
citylocation.txt

// "next day" forecasted cloud coverage (%) for 
// each [x,y] grid-area
cloudcover.txt

// "next day" forecasted atmospheric pressure intensity (%) for
// each [x,y] grid-area
pressure.txt
```

I have written the following code to do so:

```
    // open the file
    ifstream fileio;
    fileio.open(filename);

    // check if file exists
    if (!fileio.is_open()) {
        cout << "File does not exist";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        return -1;
    }

    // read file
    string word;
    fileio >> word;
    while(fileio.good()) {
        fileio.ignore(100, '\n');
        cout << word << " ";
        fileio >> word;
    }

    // close file
    fileio.close();
```

And I get the following output:

```
// // GridX_IdxRange=0-8 // // GridY_IdxRange=0-8 // citylocation.txt // // cloudcover.txt // // pressure.txt
```

How do I read the file in a way that it ignores empty lines and the lines with comments? Displaying only the important information?

Comment: Use an if statement to check if the string is empty or not before you print?

Comment: You also may consider using regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks, I have managed to solve it using the following method:   word.erase(remove(word.begin(), word.end(), '/'), word.end());

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method how to ignore:

```
// read file
string word;
while(std::getline(fileio, word))
{
    if (word.find("//") == 0)
    {
       continue;
    }
   
    cout << word << " ";
}
```

In the above version, if the text read contains "//" at the beginning of the text, the loop *continues*.  The text line is thus ignored.

The idea is to compare (validate) the text line before using.  For example, to skip blank lines, you could add an `if` statement to check for an empty string.

I also changed the `while` to use the appropriate pattern to read from a file.

You can parse the text line by using `std::istringstream` and `operator>>`.  There are many other techniques for parsing a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <algorithm>
.
.
.
word.erase(remove(word.begin(), word.end(), '/'), word.end());
```